# Unrecognized expression in attributeContains selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, fancybox

I'm using the FancyBox 1.3.1 jQuery plugin on my site. After switching from jQuery 1.4.1 to 1.9.1, I started getting this error message:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   a[rel=lightbox[ArticleImages]]

I tried changing the selector to what is described in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('a[rel="lightbox[ArticleGallery]"]')
```

But that didn't work either, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Aftwer switching from 1.4.1 to 1.9.1...` that implies that your code worked in 1.4.1. In 1.9 a lot of things have been removed or changed. If your code worked when you used 1.4 but in 1.9 it doesn't then follow the recommended guide-line on migrating to 1.9 by adding a reference to the [**migration js file**](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js) That file will include all the removed features again but add warnings to your console when used. That file was intended to support developers in migrating to 1.9 and support 3rd party plug-ins until they have upgraded to 1.9 as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between these different ways to escape square brackets inside jQuery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573178/what-is-the-difference-between-these-different-ways-to-escape-square-brackets-in)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use escape character backslash `\` for square brackets within selector.

*Change*

```
$('a[rel="lightbox[ArticleGallery]"]')
```

*To*

```
$('a[rel="lightbox\\[ArticleGallery\\]"]')
```

Comment: Though I'm sure your answer is spot on. The statement of OP is confusing: `After switching from jQuery 1.4.1 to 1.9.1, I started getting this error message:...` That would imply the code worked in the past but now doesn't. Why would the syntax be working in 1.4 but not in 1.9?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I totally get your point, but now I have both escaped the selector and added the migration.js file, but still getting this error: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel=lightbox[ArticleImages]], area[rel=lightbox[ArticleImages]]" I'm wondering where that "area" is coming from?

Comment: @Chris: If you revert back to your original syntax and back to use jQuery 1.4.1 does you code work then?

Comment: @Chris: Then using your original syntax + jQuery 1.9 and migrate-js should also work. Otherwise this is very strange indeed and might be to do with FancyBox itself somehow.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yeah.. I'll dig into this and get back to you with an answer. I might just have missed something out..

Answer (score 1):

escape the `[` operator .. since jquery consider this as atrribute selector

```
$('a[rel="lightbox\\[ArticleGallery\\]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer consists of several parts, so I'm just gonna summarize the answer here:

1. In jQuery 1.9.1 you have to escape the square brackets within the selector. Please see the answer from Adil.
2. When migrating from an older version of jQuery to 1.9.1, you could use the migration.js file to make sure any old 3rd party plug-ins still work. Please see the comment from François Wahl.

In my case though, neither of these suggestions worked. I still received the same error message.

So what I did was to migrate to fancyBox2, but then a stumbled upon another problem:

My site was using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.0 which don't work with fancyBox2. Luckily, I found the answer in [this forum thread](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862).

I had to change this peace of code in the bootstrap.js file:

```
.on('.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
```

To this:

```
.on('click.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
```

Now it works. Thx for helping out.